# Yii, apache2, and subdomains

Tags: ubuntu, yii, apache2

I hope this doesn't get flagged as it's not necessarily a question about code.  I have several sites on a dev ubuntu server. I have installed yii framework successfully.  I used yiic to create a domain / site on this server and the site is up and running without problem.  Today I went to add a subdomain to this site and, well, now I'm confused.  I went to into etc/apahe2/sites-available to add a record for the subdomain and I was surprised to see that there is no listing for the original domain.  Every other site on this server has a file except the one created using yiic.  How can this site work on apache without a file in sites-available or sites-enabled?  More to the point, how on earth do I create the subdomain?  Is it possible to simply yiic with the existing domain as doc root?

Comment: Just to be clear, yiic just generates php code, it doesn't create any server settings for you as it doesn't know the domain, what kind of server are you using etc...

Comment: This is correct.  I have no idea what got into my mind yesterday.  I feel like a complete wanker for having posted this question.  I know better than that.  I just encountered something I didn't expect and threw logic out the window.  I should delete the question to avoid further embarrassment, but instead I'll leave it so I can give you the props for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Run the yiic tool on your localhost and upload the generated files to the sub domain

Answer (score 1):

Normally ubuntu uses /etc/apache2/sites-available/default for the default domain. You can use that file to configure your subdomain

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a website needs to have a file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to work.

You can very well have a website running under `localhost/yourwebsitename` and it will work whilst not having an entry under `sites-available`.

My suggestion is: make a copy of the default file under `sites-available` and then change the contents of the file to match the root directory and the name you want you virtual host (subdomain) to have. Then run `a2ensite <yoursitename>` to have it enabled for you. Don't forget to restart apache after that.

Just a side note: a vhost (which is what you get if you do the procedure I described above) is what you should do in order to have a url like `yourapp.yourwebsite.com` to point to a specific folder (where you will have your Yii app main entry file).

If you just want to have `yoursite.com/yourapp` then you don't need to create a vhost for it. Just place the Yii project under `/var/www/yourapp` and you'll be able to access it via `localhost/yourapp`.